# Op-amp - can't choose the right model for the PCB model

Tags: operational-amplifier, pcb, ltspice, kicad

I'm thinking of using an op-amp in my circuit.

Here is my circuit:

[image: LTSpice simulation]

Now I'm making the PCB model in KiCAD:

[image: KiCad]

I don't know how to find the right model of my op-amp -> U1, U2, and U3.

Can someone point me in the right direction towards choosing the right op-amp?

Comment: I hope you thoroughly searched this one before you asked it.  If you're amature and just getting started, or only simulating and not paying for parts, you've gotta get used to hitting the datasheets.  I wouldn't mind a generalistic answer to how to pick an op amp myself, but there's a good chance it's too broad.  Rather than spend 3 months learning to calculate perfect values for a single component I'll only use once, I'll often spend a little bit extra for the modern easy to use parts.  Rail to rail is my favorite feature.

Comment: Hi @K.H. Thanks for your update. PCB is my new adventure. I don't have any experience with it. Could you help with this topic? I need to just  to know how to find the right model of op-amps.

Comment: So you need suitable input voltage, rail to rail is nice, and based on how fast you need it to respond you might need to check maximum slew rate, although that's another one where I spend the extra money instead of calculating if I have a fast circuit.  I prefer to keep them in low power circuits, but for some uses power dissipation would be relevant.

Comment: Are you thinking that 1/2 LT1366 will be fine for U1 & U2? 
What with the comparator?

Comment: Are you just using LTspice to draw your circuit, or are you actually simulating it?  Reason I ask is I'm worried about the values for R1, R2, C1, and D1.  The resistors seem awfully low, the `micro` should be a `u` instead, and the diode is using a default diode silicon PN junction model instead of an LED model.

Comment: That looks like a nice op amp to me but I would try using it at a low power level.  Ste Kulov is right, some of those are really small resistors.   All the OP amps really need to do for you is maintain mathematical relationships, so I like to run them at the smallest currents I can.  Look at the formulas for each stage, and usually what matters is the ratio between components rather than an absolute value, so try to figure out how much you can embiggen the resistors, either to the point where saving further power would be negligible, or a bit above that if you really have to.

Comment: Also what is your circuit intended to do?  You're starting with a sine wave, but your output is a half wave rectifier LED, so do you just want a flashing light?